# How do you graph the confidence intervals that results from a GARCH over a time series?

Tags: plotting, probability-or-statistics, finance, time-series, intervals

Please, does someone know how to draw a confidence intervals (from the results of a GARCH (1,1)) in a way similar to these:

[image]

*Asume an ARMA(1,1) fit the time series.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you mean the *forecast* confidence intervals?

Comment: I just understood that my original question was pretty dumb. (Thank you for the corrections in my other question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I interpret your question as focusing on the method of graphing, not the specifics of the GARCH algorithm.  As such, here is a time series, the variance (calculated on five sequential points), and the moving averages, and a combined `ListPlot`.

```
myTimeSeries = Table[.3 Sin[.1 i] + RandomReal[], {i, 1, 100}];

myVariances = Variance /@ Partition[myTimeSeries, 5, 1];

myAverages = MovingAverage[myTimeSeries, 5];

ListPlot[{myTimeSeries, myAverages, myAverages + myVariances, myAverages - myVariances},
 Joined -> {False, True, True, True},
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red, Red}]
```

[image]

Or with

```
myStandardDeviations = Sqrt /@ myVariances
```

and appropriate change of plotting function:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much David! (although I ment the specifics of the GARCH algorithm). I will use that code in my report, nonetheless. Thank you again!

Comment: (By the way, I just understood that my original question was pretty dumb)